# Get the correct credentials of existing Analytics account

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

For our project we would like to be able to access the Google Analytics accounts of our clients with a single API key. The same way as we are currently doing for their Google AdWords accounts trough our API key thats linked to our MCC account. However I don't seem able to do so trough the API for Google Analytics.

What I've done so far. I've created a new service account in the developer console and I'm able to successfully connect with the credentials. However with this account I only seem to be able to access 1 specific account. It seems like I'm forced to create credentials for each separate account. Is there a way around this so I can use a single API key to access all the accounts of our clients?